# How to tie a numeric editText field with a variable so that they can be automatically updated both ways?

Tags: android, android-edittext

In the code, I have an integer variable. In the GUI, I have a numeric editText field and two buttons which increase/decrease the value of the variable by one.

I need to link the field to the variable so that the field shows the current value of the variable every time it's changed (ie. the buttons are pressed), and set the variable value automatically when the user edits the field using the Android keyboard. Preferably, I'd like it to update the variable automatically without the need to press "Done" (if possible), however I also need to set a limit for the number. Additionally, a method needs to be called each time the value is changed.

I've been able to find how to read the value from the editText on request (to a variable), and how to set a specific text into the field (from a variable). However, this doesn't seem so practical when I need to use the field dynamically as both an input and an output. For example, when pressing the button, it changes the variable, which then changes the field, but this would also trigger the onTextChanged watcher and then again get the field text and set it to the value. I'm assuming there must be a more efficient way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to invent a wheel. Android framework provides widget for such purposes - [NumberPicker](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/NumberPicker.html).

---

**EDIT:** If you can't or don't want to use `NumberPicker`, here's the idea:

```
private class NumberPicker {
    private int value=0;

    private Button btnIncr;
    private Button btnDecr;
    private EditText editText;

    public NumberPicker(Button btnIncr, Button btnDecr, EditText editText) {
        this.btnIncr=btnIncr;
        this.btnDecr=btnDecr;
        this.editText=editText;

        this.btnIncr.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                value++;
                NumberPicker.this.editText.setText(String.valueOf(value));
            }
        });

        this.btnDecr.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                value--;
                NumberPicker.this.editText.setText(String.valueOf(value));
            }
        });

        editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                value=Integer.parseInt(s.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            }
        });
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

And don't worry about TextWatcher being triggered when value is changed by buttons. This shouldn't cause any problems.

Comment: I am using API version 7. NumberPicker widget only appears in API 11. And I also need the buttons and the field to be of a specific size and layout so I can't use a single widget.